# Jquery accordion section bounces back open when I close it

Tags: css, accordion

I have three accordion sections and I want the first to be open (with the other two closed) when I first arrive on the page. I gave all three (that is, 'accordionSectionContent' as below) seperate IDs (on top of their shared class 'accordionSectionContent') and for the first one I stated:

```
#accordion1 {
display:block;
}
```

All good, except if I click on its title at the beginning (even though it is already open), it closes and then bounces open again. If I press it again it does not bounce again but closes. The problem must be with the following code (please amend and educate):

Relevant CSS:

```
.accordionSectionContent {
display:none;
}

.accordionSectionTitle {
width:100%;
display:inline-block;
transition:all linear 0.15s;
}
```

Relevant jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function close_accordion_section() {
$('.accordion .accordionSectionTitle').removeClass('active');
$('.accordion .accordionSectionContent').slideUp(300).removeClass('open');
}

$('.accordionSectionTitle').click(function(e) {
    var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');

    if($(e.target).is('.active')) {
    close_accordion_section();
    }else {
    close_accordion_section();

    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.accordion ' + currentAttrValue).slideDown(300).addClass('open'); 
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

HTML as follows:

```
<div class="accordion">

<div class="accordionSection"><a class="accordionSectionTitle" href="#accordion1" id="accordionSectionTitle1">Info</a>
<div id="accordion1" class="accordionSectionContent">
<p>Helpful info</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="accordionSection"><a class="accordionSectionTitle" href="#accordion2" id="accordionSectionTitle2">How long will it take?</a>
<div id="accordion2" class="accordionSectionContent">
<p>An estimate of time</p>
</div>
</div>

<div class="accordionSection"><a class="accordionSectionTitle" href="#accordion3" id="accordionSectionTitle3">How do I?</a>
<div id="accordion3" class="accordionSectionContent">
<p>.</p>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: You should post your HTML.

Comment: @vanburenx HTML added as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/u6y7ezz4/1/

You might get upset, but you are missing a space :)

In your function close_accordion_section

```
function close_accordion_section() {
     $('.accordion .accordionSectionTitle').removeClass('active');
     $('.accordion.accordionSectionContent').slideUp(300).removeClass('open');
}
```

You are missing a space at the second line between .accordion and .accordionSectionContent

The fix is:

```
function close_accordion_section() {
     $('.accordion .accordionSectionTitle').removeClass('active');
     $('.accordion .accordionSectionContent').slideUp(300).removeClass('open');
}
```

Comment: Haha, bad 'copy-paste' editing on my behalf. Not in original. Will update my edit accordingly.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle. The issue is that you were setting #accordion1 to block, but you were not setting the class **active** and **open**
https://jsfiddle.net/u6y7ezz4/1/

Comment: Thanks @nimzur. You provided the solution.

Comment: For everyone else, solution found in the 'fiddle' link.

Answer (score 0):

See if this is what you're trying to accomplish.

```js
var headers = $('.accordion-section a');
var contentAreas = $('.accordion-section-content').hide();
var firstContentAreas = $('.accordion-section-content').hide().first().show();

headers.click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();
  var panel = $(this).parent('div').next('div');
  var isOpen = panel.is(':visible');

  contentAreas.slideUp();
  panel[isOpen ? 'slideUp' : 'slideDown']()
    .trigger(isOpen ? 'hide' : 'show');

  $('.accordion-section a').not(this).removeClass('accordion-section-title');
  $(this).toggleClass('accordion-section-title');


  return false;
});
```

```css
.accordion {
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #444;
  border-radius: 0px;
  font-family: "Verdana";
}
.accordion-section {
  clear: both;
  text-align: left;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  min-width: 200px;
  min-height: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #444;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 10px 10px;
}
.accordion-section a,
.accordion-section a:active,
.accordion-section a:visited {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
}
.accordion-section-content {
  padding: 5px 15px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-section"> <a href="#accordion-1" class="accordion-section-title">Accordion Section #1</a>

  </div>
  <div id="accordion-1" class="accordion-section-content">
    <p>Mauris interdum fringilla augue vitae tincidunt. Curabitur vitae tortor id eros euismod ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent nulla mi, rutrum ut feugiat at, vestibulum ut neque? Cras
      tincidunt enim vel aliquet facilisis. Duis congue ullamcorper vehicula. Proin nunc lacus, semper sit amet elit sit amet, aliquet pulvinar erat. Nunc pretium quis sapien eu rhoncus. Suspendisse ornare gravida mi, et placerat tellus tempor vitae.</p>
  </div>
  <!--end .accordion-section-content-->
  <!--end .accordion-section-->
  <div class="accordion-section"> <a href="#accordion-2" class="accordion-section-title">Accordion Section #2</a>

  </div>
  <div id="accordion-2" class="accordion-section-content">
    <p>Mauris interdum fringilla augue vitae tincidunt. Curabitur vitae tortor id eros euismod ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Praesent nulla mi, rutrum ut feugiat at, vestibulum ut neque? Cras
      tincidunt enim vel aliquet facilisis. Duis congue ullamcorper vehicula. Proin nunc lacus, semper sit amet elit sit amet, aliquet pulvinar erat. Nunc pretium quis sapien eu rhoncus. Suspendisse ornare gravida mi, et placerat tellus tempor vitae.</p>
  </div>
  <!--end .accordion-section-content-->
  <!--end .accordion-section-->
  <div class="accordion-section"> <a href="#accordion-3" class="accordion-section-title">Accordion Section #3</a>

  </div>
  <div id="accordion-3" class="accordion-section-content">
    <p>Mauris interdum fringilla augue vitae tincidunt. Curabitur vitae tortor id eros euismod ultrices. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridicu.</p>
    <!--accordion-section-content-->
    <!--end .accordion-section-->
  </div>
  <!--end .accordion-->
```

Comment: This is what I was trying to accomplish. Nevertheless, the text (accordion-section-content) in the slide above now moves when you close the slide below it. This did not happen before, and is undesired :s Any solution?